# How to loop for adding BatchNormalization after every conv2d layer in pretrain model

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I have a pretrain model (vgg16) from keras.  I'm trying to add BatchNormalization layer after every conv2d by looping.  However, it seems that I could not all of them together.  Here is my code.

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input
from keras.models import Model

input_tensor = Input(shape=(256, 256, 3))
pretrain = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_tensor=input_tensor)

            model = pretrain.layers[0].input
            for i in range(len(pretrain.layers)):
                x = pretrain.layers[i].output
                if "conv" in pretrain.layers[i].name:
                    x = pretrain.layers[i].output
                    x = BatchNormalization(axis=-1)(x)

                model = Model(input=model.input, output=x)
```

May I have your suggestions?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should build a new model by copying layers from VGG and adding your own where you want.

The problem now is that the conv. layers are connected to the batch norm but which are not connected to anything.